# Get Interfaces but not the base one

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface

Here is little problem.

I have interface "ISuperAbility".
And I have some superAbilities(also interfaces) which inherited from ISuperAbility.

So, I have a dictionary with a Type as a key, and double(points) as a Value.
In that dictionary I have next data:

```
        abilityPoints = new Dictionary<Type, double>();
        abilityPoints.Add(typeof(IFlyable), 2.0f);
        abilityPoints.Add(typeof(IInvisible), 4.0f);
        abilityPoints.Add(typeof(IMindsReadable), 6.0f);
        abilityPoints.Add(typeof(IWallWalkable), 1.0f);
```

All these "abilities" is a interfaces that inheried from ISuperAbility.

Then, I have hero, for example "Mysterio", that implements two interfaces:
IMindsReadble
IInvisible

SO, when I want to get all points on certain hero, I do the next thing:

```
        public static double ForceOfHuman(Human hero)
        {
            double force = 0;

            Console.WriteLine(hero.GetType());
            Type[] humanInterfaces = hero.GetType().GetInterfaces();

            foreach (Type humanInterface in humanInterfaces)
            {
                if (humanInterface.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISuperAbility)))
                {
                    force += XMenLaboratory.abilityPoints[humanInterface];
                }
            }

            return force;
        }
```

And after this I have an exception that tell me about problem cause dictionary does not have such a key. And a key is "ISuperAbility".

So that search in method return also a base interface. Is it normal ? I think, more than that.

So, what can I do for getting interfaces except base one ?

**EDIT 1**

I must say, that I was wrong at certain moment.
My abilities that inheried from ISuperAbility does not reach this condition

```
if (humanInterface.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISuperAbility)))
    {
        force += XMenLaboratory.abilityPoints[humanInterface];
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Solution, that I prefered was a next one:

```
                if (typeof(ISuperAbility).IsAssignableFrom(humanInterface) && humanInterface != typeof(ISuperAbility))
                {
                    force += XMenLaboratory.abilityPoints[humanInterface];
                }
```

Tank you all.

Comment: Is your `IsAssignableFrom` the right way round? Wouldn't you be looking for interfaces that are `typeof(ISuperAbility).IsAssignableFrom( humanInterface)`?

Comment: @IanMercer Sorry, I do not understand you. Is my code not work for my purpose ? Is there a logic trouble ?

Comment: @VladislavHromyh What Ian Mercer is saying is that in order to check if `humanInterface` inherits `ISuperAbility` you should use `typeof(ISuperAbility).IsAssignableFrom( humanInterface)`. Your condition is wrong, that's why it cannot be reach.

Comment: Your condition is backwards. `IFlyable` is not assignable from `ISuperAbility`, it is assignable TO `ISuperAbility`.

Comment: Oh, thank you guys. I used it at the very first time, so I was wrong in way of use method IsAssignableFrom().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude interface `ISuperAbility` from your `foreach` statement:

```
foreach (Type humanInterface in humanInterfaces.Where(i => i != typeof(ISuperAbility)))
```

This way you will get all ability interfaces, except for `ISuperAbility`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as @dotnetom says. It's simple (and probably best) working solution.

Or - if you want some universal solution - you can call "GetInterfaces()" on all types (types of interface). And if the result will be empty array/null, you will know, it's "root interface" and skip thath.

**EDIT:**
Sample code:

```
public static double ForceOfHuman(Human hero)
{
    double force = 0;

    Console.WriteLine(hero.GetType());
    Type[] humanInterfaces = hero.GetType().GetInterfaces();

    foreach (Type humanInterface in humanInterfaces)
    {
        if (humanInterface.GetInterfaces().Length < 1)
        {
            // the interface is "base interface", so we ignore it
            continue;
        }

        // we are suming the ability point from "derived interface"
        force += XMenLaboratory.abilityPoints[humanInterface];
    }

    return force;
}
```

Comment: Hmgh... Could you repharse main idea, please ?
What do you mean by words "you can call "GetInterfaces()" on all types"

Comment: Oh... I understand. Thank you for example, I will try it.